# Ruby on Rails 4 executing shell command daemon

Tags: shell, ruby-on-rails-4, spawn

I use the built-in options to distribute my Ruby on Rails app.
Meaning I start the server with

```
rails s -e production -p 80 -d
```

But as soon as I append the daemon flag `-d` to this command I can no longer execute shell commands...

I tried a wide spectrum of possibilities to execute commands e.g.:

```
system(cmd)

%x[ #{cmd} ]

`#{cmd}`

Process.detach(spawn(cmd))

Process.fork do
  p = spawn(cmd)
  Process.detach(p)
end
```

And I have no idea what else I can do...
Would be very grateful for a hint/solution...

Some informations to the running system:
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Rail Version: 4.0.2
I log via ssh onto the computer and start the rails server
I've tested all commands listed above, they all work without the daemon flag but will not work with it...

Thanks in advance.
Greetings Alex

Answer (score 0):

Failure found.

There is not connection between Server as daemon and no processes/shell commands.

I was just stupid enough to look in the wrong dirs...

Note:
If you execute the rails server as daemon it is no longer a process of the user but of the root. Just check the next time if all paths are bullet proof.

Comment: So how did you manage to fix this? I am having this issue now.